# Dynamic cast fail issue

Tags: system-verilog

```
class base;
  int a = 15;
endclass

class extended extends base;
  int b = 2;
endclass

module top;
  initial begin
    base       base;
    extended  extend;

    extend = new();
    base    = new();
    $cast(extend, base);
    $display(extend.a);
  end
endmodule
```

I'm trying to undersatnd $cast method in systemverilog as the above code, But I've got error messages.

```
ncsim> source /incisiv/15.20/tools/inca/files/ncsimrc
ncsim> run
    $cast(extend, base);
        |
ncsim: *E,BCLCST (./testbench.sv,18|8): Invalid cast: a value with the class datatype '$unit_0x4ccdf83b::base' cannot be assigned to a class variable with the datatype '$unit_0x4ccdf83b::extended'.
         15
ncsim: *W,RNQUIE: Simulation is complete.
ncsim> exit
Exit code expected: 0, received: 1
```

Why does it make a error?

## update 2

I've got some  more test code for understanding the $cast().

test code.1

```
class base;
  int a = 15;
endclass

class extended extends base;
  int b = 2;
endclass

module top;
  initial begin
    base       b;
    extended  e;

    e = new();
    b    = new();
    $cast(b, e);
    //b=e;
    $display(e.a);
  end
endmodule
```

test code 2

```
class base;
  int a = 15;
endclass

class extended extends base;
  int b = 2;
endclass

module top;
  initial begin
    base       b;
    extended  e;

    e = new();
    b    = new();
    //$cast(b, e);
    b=e;
    $display(e.a);
  end
endmodule
```

When I compiled the both test code.1 and test code.2, the result the same.
So I'm confused that why do we use '$cast()' methods?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$cast` is failing correctly as specified by the LRM. You have constructed a `base` class type object and stored its handle in a `base` class variable. (BTW, a bad idea to use the same name for both as you have now hidden the `base` type name). Now you are trying to assign the `base` handle to class variable of class type `extend`. `$cast` fails because the object your are tying to assign a handle to `extended` never constructed an `extend` object. Had the cast been allowed to succeed, the original handle in `extended` would have been replaced with a handle to a `base` object, and the reference to  `extend.b` would be fatal since that variable does not exist.

The purpose of `$cast` is when you have handle stored in a base class variable, and that handle refers to an extended class object. The `$cast` allows you to move that handle to an extended class variable by checking the object it refers to first before making the assignment.

Please see my seminar on [SystemVerilog OOP](http://go.mentor.com/SV-OOP) as well as short post on [class terminology](http://go.mentor.com/class-on-classes).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following example for studying. the last 'printer()' statement will fail because you cannot cast non descendant of ext to 'ext' int he function

```
class base;
  local string a;
  function new();
    a = "I am a";
  endfunction
  function print();
    $display(a);
  endfunction
endclass

class ext extends base;
  local string b;
  function new();
    b = "i am b";
  endfunction
  function print();
    $display(b);
  endfunction
endclass


function printer(base p);
  ext e;
  $cast(e, p);

  e.print();
  p.print();
endfunction

program P;
  base b = new();
  ext e = new();

  initial begin
    printer(e);
    printer(b); // << this will fail
  end
endprogram
```